# Entity framework ASP MVC 4, Referencing the wrong table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I am using the code first approach with a local database (localdb\11.0v) in ASP MVC 4. I have created my entity

```
public class Service
    {
        public int ServiceID { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    }
```

My DbContext

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Service> Service { get; set; }
    }
```

My repositories

```
public interface IServiceRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Service> Service { get; }
    }
```

Interface

```
public class EFServiceRepository : IServiceRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Service> Service
        {
            get { return context.Service; }
        }
    }
```

I am using Ninject for the binding

```
 ninjectKernel.Bind<IServiceRepository>().To<EFServiceRepository>();
```

With the controller referencing the ninject kernel bind

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            return View(repo.Service);
        }
```

So this all works which is good but it does not work the way that i want it to. It pulls a list from the table "Services" but i want it to pull data from the table "Service". I dont understand why this is happening. I did have the var names plural so they were "Services" but that should not make a difference ( should it? ) I changed them all to "Service" in hope that would solve it. I really feel like i was understanding all this until now.

We have "business" rules for the db and they need to be singular names + i really want to understand why it is using the "Services" table and not the "Service" table. I only added the "Services" table to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add this code into "Using" Blocks of EFDbContext class:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions
```

Then Add this code into EFDbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the quick reply. Is ModelBuilder part of a reference i should be using. Or should i create a class for it ( sorry if this is a noob question , having been doing this for to long )

Comment: Not really. I have add the code and I get a reference for the <PluraluzingTableNAmeConvention> But i am not sure about the (ModelBuilder modelBuilder) it says

Comment: "The type of namespace name ModelBuilder could not be found, are you missing an assembly refernece

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30206/discussion-between-bappi-datta-and-gerdi)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to override Entity Framework's naming conventions wrt table names:

First is through data annotations on the entity class:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Service")]
public class Service
{
    ...
```

Second is through fluent mapping in the context class itself:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Service>().ToTable("Service");
```

Comment: So the naming convention is to hit plural tables even if you have defined the table name in the code? this seems really old

Comment: Well, you don't define tables names in code, just class names. To translate them to plural tables is just a convention (as Bappi Datta shows).